# Identify multiple containers for vuejs components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a website where I have classic multiple pages powered by blade templates, but I want to use vuejs2 components for the most dynamic needs.

It's working fine, but I couldn't find a convenient way to declare containers parsed by VueJs for components.

I want to use many components in many places, but I can't declare a big main container as VueJs container because of conflicts with `<script>` tags.
If I do that I get errors like : `- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.`

I currently do something like that in my `app.js` file :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#need-components-1'
});
new Vue({
  el: '#need-components-2'
});
new Vue({
  el: '#need-components-3'
});
```

I really don't like it, I'd like to be able to declare either the whole content as VueJs-able, or at least use a common class or attribute for containers. Here I need to add a new id each time I want to use a new place for components. Moreover, VueJs posts console errors for every time an element is not found because obviously they are not all always loaded.

Is there any elegant / convenient way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't necessarily need a unique id for each Vue, just some identifier that that element should be a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some identifier that an element is a root Vue and then, when the page loads, iterate over the elements you find on the page and create Vue's for them.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const vues = document.querySelectorAll("[data-vue]")
for (let v of vues)
  new Vue({el: v, data: {message: "Hello from Vue"}})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div data-vue="true">
   <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>
<h4>Some other page content</h4>
<div data-vue="true">
  <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>
<h4>Some other page content</h4>
<div data-vue="true">
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>
```

Obviously you'll need to figure out a way to marry the appropriate data with the correct Vue if it should be different from Vue to Vue.